# PHP Conditional Logic

Tags: php, conditional-statements, logic, if-statement

In PHP, is the following logic allowed

```
If (x && y)
  //Do A
Elseif (x)
  // Do B
Elseif (y)
  // Do C
Else
  // Do D
```

Basically, are you allowed to use more than one elseif?

Comment: Why couldn't you just test this?

Answer (score 11):

Yes:

```
if ($x && $y) {
  //Do A
} else if ($x) {
  // Do B
} else if ($y) {
  // Do C
} else {
  // Do D
}
```

Another format useful for HTML files

```
<?php if ($x && $y): ?>
  Element A
<?php elseif ($x): ?>
  Element B
<?php elseif ($y): ?>
  Element C
<?php else: ?>
  Element D
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: The space between else and if is not necessary in PHP - there is an elseif control statement.

Comment: tomato / tomatoe ;) just more used to writing `else if`

Comment: i figured if someone ever googled PHP conditional else - they might want to find a good answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

yup

```
if(this == this && this == this){
   //this and that
}else if(this == that || this == that){
  //this or that
}else{
  //anything else
}
```

Comment: I'll also point out that you're using an assignment operator (=) and not a comparison check (==).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although if the test is simple (`$a == $b`), use a switch instead:

```
switch ($a) {
    case $b:
        break;
    case $c:
        break;
    default:
        //Like else
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Please see [https://www.php.net/elseif](https://www.php.net/else) and https://www.php.net/elseif.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if($x)
    // for one line of code
elseif($y)
    // also for one line of code

if($x) {
    // for more than
    // one line of code
} elseif($y) {
    // also for multi-
    // line codes
}
```

and

```
if($x):
    // multi-line
endif;
```